Kernel convergence for finite rank approximations of compact operators
Suppose $T:X \rightarrow Y$ is a compact Hilbert space operator, and $\{T_n\}$ is a sequence of finite rank maps such that $T_n \rightarrow T$ in the operator norm. We may further suppose that $\text{rank}(T_n) \leq \text{rank}(T)$ for all $n$.
Let $P$ denote the orthogonal projection onto $\ker(T)$, and $P_n$ denote the orthogonal projection onto $\ker(T_n)$. It is immediately clear that $P_n \not \rightarrow P$ in general. For example, take $T$ to be any compact operator with trivial kernel. But I’m curious about when $P_n \rightarrow P$ in both the operator norm and pointwise.
Unfortunately, most of the results I can find seem to look at the case where $T_n$ and $T$ all have finite dimensional kernels of the same dimension. This will never be the case for finite rank approximations of a compact operator.
One point of interest would be to consider the case of finite rank $T$. In this case, we eventually have that $\text{rank}(T_n) = \text{rank}(T)$ for all $n$ sufficiently large. Even here though, I have failed to find a way to show even pointwise convergence of $P_n \rightarrow P$. If the Moore-Penrose Pseudoinverse were continuous on operators of the same rank, this would give a proof of convergence in the operator norm. However, I cannot find such a result for infinite dimensional Hilbert spaces.
Any help would be appreciated.
